# Assign callback function to a variable and call outside of higher-order function

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I wish to assign a callback function to a component variable... E.g.

```
...
export class MyComponent {
       private myCompVar: any;

       myFunc = function(callback: (number) => void): void {
              this.myCompVar = callback;
       }
}
```

...then call this callback function later on from within another function in MyComponent. E.g.:

```
...
export class MyComponent {
       private myCompVar: any;
       ...
       myOtherFunc(event): void {
               ...
               this.myCompVar(callbackParam);
       }
}
```

However, when I implement this like above, an error occurs saying that 'this.myCompVar' is undefined when I attempt to call it inside 'myOtherFunc'. This puzzles me as I have confirmed that the callback is being correctly set to it in 'myFunc' and that its type is 'function'. 'myOtherFunc' is also getting called after 'myFunc' is called and returns, as expected.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `function` you're losing the correct `this` context. I'd propose using a lambda (fat arrow function) instead, which correctly binds to the right `this` context:

```
myFunc = (callback: (number) => void): void => {
    this.myCompVar = callback;
}
```

Comment: Holy cow, it worked perfectly! Rinukkusu, you are a genius and a scholar. Thank you so much! Have a smashingly great day.

Comment: Haha, no problem - same to you, too! :)